# Address family not supported by protocol: Error using sockets and WSL2

Tags: c, sockets, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, can-bus

I am having an error trying to setup sockets and using them in C. I am using WSL2 and get the error socket open failed Address family not supported by protocol for this code:

```
int s;
if ((s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW)) < 0) {
perror("socket open failed");
return 1;
}
```

How can I resolve this? I just installed wsl2 and haven't added many packages.
Thanks for the help!

I tried searching online but couldn't find anything, also tried sudo modprobe vcan but nothing worked.

Comment: It sounds like WSL doesn't support raw sockets or `PF_CAN`.

Comment: ... Not necessarily WSL itself, but at least whichever Linux you installed in yours.

Comment: Side note: you should use *address family* macros such as `AF_CAN` with `socket()`.  Not *protocol family* constants such as `PF_CAN`.  Many of the corresponding address and protocol family numbers match, but such matching is not guaranteed.

Comment: During your online search, you found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5533) and followed the instructions to enable CAN support in the WSL kernel?